# ACF Values Don't Show After Import Unless I Edit/Update Post

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, import, bulk-import

I am importing CPT's using WP All Import which include ACF field values. When I import, the values don't show on the front end unless I open/edit/publish. I have tried several options including bulk edit (tags, etc) as well as a code snippet I found, but nothing seems to work. Here's the snippet I am currently using, with menu_item being the post type.

Any help would be AWESOME. Thanks ahead of time!

```
function my_update_posts() {
    //$myposts = get_posts('showposts=-1');//Retrieve the posts you are targeting
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'menu_items',
        'numberposts' => -1
    );
    $myposts = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($myposts as $mypost){
        $mypost->post_title = $mypost->post_title.'';
        wp_update_post( $mypost );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'my_update_posts' );
```